# how to hook up 2 thermostats in series?

Tags: heating

I have a tenant on the 1st floor who controls the thermostat. It's constantly on 80 and the 2nd floor is dying from the heat. Can I install a 2nd thermostat in the basement and limit the heat output?

Comment: depends on the installation of the heating system. get a pro to take a look at it, you may just be able to turn down the airflow to the second floor.

Comment: How do you have a legal rental unit with two separate spaces sharing one heat source and one thermostat???

Answer (score 1):

If you install two thermostats in series, they'll both have to be calling for heat for the heating to come on.

For example if thermostat 1 is set to 80, and thermostat 2 is set to 75. When the temperature drops below 78, thermostat 1 will close and call for heat. However, the heating will not come on.  When the temperature drops below 73, thermostat 2 will close and call for heat.  At this point the heating will come on, and will stay on until thermostat 2 is satisfied.

In a situation like this, thermostat 1 will never be satisfied, and will always be calling for heat.  You'll basically be bypassing thermostat 1. So the temperature near thermostat 2 will be comfortable,  while the temperature near thermostat 1 will likely be somewhere less than 80.

Keep in mind, however, if the user of thermostat 1 figures out what you've done. They could turn their thermostat way down, and the heating would never come on.

Answer (score 1):

The best (but not cheap) answer would be to make the two units separate heating zones, installing dampers (if forced-hot-air) or additional pumps and loops (if forced-hot-water) to direct heat only to the thermostat which is calling for it. That would give you full independent control within each space. Nothing else is likely to do so, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can install two sensors and remove the thermostat to an area of your control.  The sensors are in series to the one thermostat.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are basic, analog/mechanical thermostats then yes, you can wire as many in series as you want. Heating will continue until the room with the lowest-set thermostat reaches that temperature.

However, you must consider the whole-building heating process as just putting a 'stat in a random location could easily make the problem worse. It sounds like putting one in the second floor would be a better solution.